# How to validate a password with yup when minimum amount of conditions met

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup, react-hook-form

I am trying to make a password validation using yup where at least 3 of 4 password conditions are met.  I am having trouble finding an existing way to do this.

My requirements are this:

> At least 8 characters It must use characters from at least three of
> the following four character types: • English alphabet uppercase
> letters (A-Z) • English alphabet lowercase letters (a-z) • Numerals
> (0-9) • Non-alphanumeric symbols (such as !, #, $, %)

And my yup validation (using react-hook-form) is this:

```
newPassword: yup
.string()
.required('Please enter a password')
.min(8, 'Password too short')
.matches(/^(?=.*[a-z])/, 'Must contain at least one lowercase character')
.matches(/^(?=.*[A-Z])/, 'Must contain at least one uppercase character')
.matches(/^(?=.*[0-9])/, 'Must contain at least one number')
.matches(/^(?=.*[!@#%&])/, 'Must contain at least one special character'),
```

The problem is of course this makes all 4 conditions required, when only at least 3 of the 4 need to be.  Any help on solving this would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i would advise you to use the yup method `yup.test()` to write custom test functions like this one below when you have custom tests and you can extend it also with `yup.addMethod()` if you want to reuse the test function

```
 password: Yup.string()
      .required("Please enter a password")
      .min(8, "Password too short")
      .test("isValidPass", " is not valid", (value, context) => {
        const hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test(value);
        const hasLowerCase = /[a-z]/.test(value);
        const hasNumber = /[0-9]/.test(value);
        const hasSymbole = /[!@#%&]/.test(value);
        let validConditions = 0;
        const numberOfMustBeValidConditions = 3;
        const conditions = [hasLowerCase, hasUpperCase, hasNumber, hasSymbole];
        conditions.forEach((condition) =>
          condition ? validConditions++ : null
        );
        if (validConditions >= numberOfMustBeValidConditions) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      })
```

this is a demo [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-slack-yx3w0) with a working example

Comment: '[0-9]' can be replaced with '\d' for avoiding [Sonar Lint](https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-6353) warning 

Answer (score 3):

Hope so it will be help full (with Password and Confirm Password Validation) and it will catch the all Password requirements.

```
import * as yup from 'yup';

 const PasswordValidation = yup.object().shape({
  password: yup
    .string()
    .required('Password Required')
    .min(8, 'Password too short')
    .test(
      'isValidPass',
      'Passowrd must be 8 char (One UpperCase & One Symbol)',
      (value: any, context: any) => {
        const hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test(value);
        const hasNumber = /[0-9]/.test(value);
        const hasLowerCase = /[a-z]/.test(value);
        const hasSymbole = /["!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"]/.test(value);
        let validConditions = 0;
        const numberOfMustBeValidConditions = 3;
        const conditions = [hasUpperCase, hasLowerCase, hasNumber, hasSymbole];
        conditions.forEach(condition => (condition ? validConditions++ : null));
        if (validConditions >= numberOfMustBeValidConditions) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    ),
  confirmpassword: yup
    .string()
    .required('Confirm Password Required')
    .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match'),
});
```